# c# windows mobile application on other platforms?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

can windows phone application with C# programmed work with Symbian, android, IOS; if yes, how?
i used Local database in application also

Answer (score 4):

Symbian, not at all.  For Android and iOS, [Xamarin's Mono products](http://xamarin.com/) might allow you to recompile the app for those platforms, though the UI code will have to be rewritten.  There's no way to get the Phone binaries as-is to just run on those other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Just to slightly disagree with @ctacke's answer.

Technically, there is an old Microsoft Silverlight 2 port out there for Symbian: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7890

But it's not been updated in a long time - and I don't really think it's that usable for development moving forwards.

Comment: A few years ago there were also a company called red five labs from South Africa who sold Net60. It worked on netcf winforms, and it worked - I even ported some open netcf gps code in. However... the company ran out of cash, i heard the investors took all the ip and I never heard of it again - http://vimeo.com/4329331

Comment: Yeah, I played with Red 5 ages ago and even talked with them about what they needed to add.  They looked good and had a nice talent pool, too bad they ran out of cash.  Would have been nicer if they'd pushed it into the wild before closing shop, as abandoned code never benefits anyone.

Comment: I talked to one of them as they were closing - the investors were looking to sell the code on - fair enough - I guess they did pay for it :)

Comment: Sure, but they found no takers.  Would have loved to have seen it Codeplexed - yet another cool thing to suck up the time I don't have.